# Pivoting on multiple columns with multiple sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below sample data:

```sql
+------------+--------+--------+----------+----------+
|    Type    | Total1 | Total2 | Account1 | Account2 |
+------------+--------+--------+----------+----------+
| Adjustment |  -2.14 |   2.14 |     1220 |     4110 |
| Adjustment |   0.21 |  -0.21 |     1220 |     4110 |
| Adjustment |  -6.43 |   6.43 |     1220 |     1220 |
+------------+--------+--------+----------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is PIVOT/SUM with the Account1 column related to the Total1 column, and the Account2 table related to the Total2 column.

But when pivoting I need to pivot by Account1 and Account2 combined, and sum by the related Total column for that Account Code, so with this sample data I finish up with the following result:

```sql
+------------+-------+------+
|    Type    | 1220  | 4110 |
+------------+-------+------+
| Adjustment | -1.93 | 1.93 |
+------------+-------+------+
```

My two attempts so far consist of this but it's not quite there. Can someone please advise what I'm missing?

```sql
select 
    Type,
    sum([1220]) as [1220],
    sum([4110]) as [4110]
from #temp
    pivot
    (
      sum(Total1)
      for Account1 in ([1220],[4110])
    ) p
group by Type

select
    Type,
    sum(case When Account1 = '1220' Then Total1 WHEN Account2 = '1220' Then Total2 end) as [1220],
    sum(case When Account1 = '4110' Then Total1 WHEN Account2 = '4110' Then Total2 end) as [4110]
from #temp
group by Type
```

Sample Data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    Type varchar(50),
    Total1 money,
    Total2 money,
    Account1 int,
    Account2 int
)

insert into #temp (Type, Total1, Total2, Account1, Account2)
    select 'Adjustment', '-2.14', '2.14', '1220', '4110'
    union all
    select 'Adjustment', '0.21', '-0.21', '1220', '4110'
    union all
    select 'Adjustment', '-6.43', '6.43', '1220', '1220'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try handling this by taking a union approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [Type], Total1 AS Total, Account1 AS Account FROM #temp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Type], Total2, Account2 FROM #Temp
)

SELECT
    [Type],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Account = '1220' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS [1220],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Account = '4110' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS [4110]
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Type;
```

[image]

### Demo

The basic strategy here is to bring all accounts and totals into two separate columns, and then aggregate/pivot just over those single columns.  This gets around the problem of having the data you want to aggregate across multiple columns.  The best long term fix might be to change your data structure to just have a single column for the account and total.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a `CROSS APPLY` to `UNPIVOT` your data, and then **PIVOT**

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select A.[Type] 
              ,B.*
         from #Temp A
         Cross Apply ( values (Total1,Account1)
                             ,(Total2,Account2)
                     ) B (Value,Item)
       ) Src
 Pivot (sum(Value) for Item in ([1220],[4110]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
Type        1220    4110
Adjustment  -1.93   1.93
```